# Why is it taking so long for GUI to Sync? My balance is still at zero

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, mining

I have tried for the last few days to sync my windows gui monero wallet. It seems difficult, my balance is showing at zero - after 8 days mining, is this because the wallet hasn't synced yet or 8 days mining in minexmr at 150 H/S gives zero payout? Why does the synchronisation process take so long? It seems like a lot of effort compared to other wallets/currencies I have used which 'sync' in one second. Why can't my wallet just find me in the blockchain and tell me what my balance is? Or - as I say is it just because there probably hasn't been a payout yet. What do you think people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my balance is showing at zero - after 8 days mining, is this because the wallet hasn't synced yet or 8 days mining in minexmr at 150 H/S gives zero payout?

The minimum payout is 0.5 XMR from minexmr, as far as I know.  At 150 h/s, it will take several months to reach that threshold.

> Why does the synchronisation process take so long?

The Monero blockchain is opaque.  Balances aren't stored at addresses like in nearly every other blockchain.  Your wallet needs to scan blocks to try to "unlock" all the unique, one-time addresses on the blockchain to see which outputs are owned by it.  The most trustless and private way to do this is to first download a copy of the blockchain locally, which can take from several hours to several days.

> It seems like a lot of effort compared to other wallets/currencies I have used which 'sync' in one second. Why can't my wallet just find me in the blockchain and tell me what my balance is?

See previous answer.

> Or - as I say is it just because there probably hasn't been a payout yet. What do you think people?

In this case, it sounds like your wallet is probably empty anyway.  But, in general, it does take longer for new Monero users to get up and running than for other cryptocurrencies for the reasons mentioned above.