# Monero Wallet is synchronized but Balance is still 0

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am a Monero "newbie" :) and transferred for the first time from the Kraken website Monero coins to my wallet, but even after being completely synchronized the balance in the wallet is still zero. I have also received the Transaction ID, which states "Successful" - Does anybody know what might be the source of error here?

Many thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it taking so long for GUI to Sync? My balance is still at zero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6528/why-is-it-taking-so-long-for-gui-to-sync-my-balance-is-still-at-zero)

Comment: Same problem here.
Supposed to receive Monero and transaction record ok but never received the crypto.

Comment: @mat & DanZan - Can you have a look at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance